# unresolved external symbol mingw_getsp

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2005, png, mingw, mingw-w64

I have compiled the `libpng` using 64 bit x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc compiler and I've written a wrapper for that `libpng` using visual c++ compiled in 64 bit windows 7 platform and use the following additional library to build the wrapper (i.e libpng,libzlib,libgcc).while I try to run the visual c++ wrapper I got the following error. please any one help me to solve this problem.

```
unresolved external symbol mingw_getsp referenced in function read_png.
unresolved external symbol __strtod refernced in function png_handle_sCAL
```

my include file is like this

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif /*  __cplusplus */

#define PNG_BYTES_TO_CHECK 4

#define OK 0
#define UNSUP_IMG_FMT -1
#define ERROR_FILE_READ -2
#define ERROR_CREATE_PNG_STRUCT -3
#define ERROR_CREATE_INFO_STRUCT -4
#define ERROR_SET_JMP -5
#define UNSUP_DEPTH -6
#define UNSUP_COLOR -7
#define UNSUP_INTRLC -8
#define UNSUP_HEIGHT_WIDTH -9

struct fakefile
{
    unsigned char *ptr;
    size_t lim;
};
int check_if_png(char*);
int check_if_pngbuffer(unsigned char *);
int read_png(char*,int*,int*,unsigned char**);
int read_pngbuffer(unsigned char*,int ,int*,int*,unsigned char **);
int write_png(char*,int,int,unsigned char*,int);
int write_pngbuffer(unsigned char**,int*,int,int,unsigned char*,int);


#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif /*  __cplusplus */
```

one more thing I had do the same for 32 bit windows xp it works properly

First I compiled the zlib and created the libzlib.lib

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -c *.c
x86_64-w64-mingw32-ar rcs libzlib.lib *.o
del *.o
```

then I created the libpng like this manner

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -I ../zlib -c *.c
x86_64-w64-mingw32-ar rcs libpng.lib *.o
del *.o
```

then I created the pngreadwrite.c & pngreadwrite.h wrapper libpngrw.lib

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -I ../zlib -c pngreadwrite.c
x86_64-w64-mingw32-ar rcs libpngrw.lib *.o
del *.o
```

by using the following library I will try to create a visual c++ static library named LSpng.lib. and successfully created the static library LSpng. I got the following error when I run the LSpng.lib in 64 bit windows machine.

```
“error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mingw_getsp referenced in function read_png”
“error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol mingw_getsp”
“error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol mingw_getsp”
“error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol  __strtod referenced in function png_handle_sCAL”

LSpng.lib(pngreadwrite.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol mingw_getsp referenced in function read_png
LSpng.lib(pngread.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol mingw_getsp
LSpng.lib(pngread.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol mingw_getsp
LSpng.lib(pngrutil.o) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol  __strtod referenced in function png_handle_sCAL
```

Comment: Have you forgotten to include some libraries?

Comment: @bash.d i include libgcc library. if any other library is need to load

Comment: please show your `#include`s

Comment: @bash.d libpng.lib,libzlib.lib,libgcc.lib

Comment: @bash.d this is my #include #ifndef PNGREADWRITE_H #define PNGREADWRITE_H #ifdef __cplusplus extern "C" { #endif /.../declaration #ifdef __cplusplus } #endif #endif

Comment: Please post this into your question

Comment: To clarify - you built the libpng using MinGW-64 and you're getting the error trying to build some sort of wrapper library using VC2005?  Can you post details of how you built the libpng using MinGW and how you're trying to build the VC++ wrapper library? Is the linker error coming from VC's linker or the MinGW ld linker?

Comment: @MichaelBurr i had edited the question and give the entire details.

Comment: Thanks for posting that. But, I still don't understand what the last couple sentences that start with "by using the following library..." mean.

Comment: @MichaelBurr by using libpng.lib,libzlib.lib,libpngrw.lib,libgcc.lib i had created the static library LSpng.lib

Comment: @MichaelBurr one more thing i did the same thing in 32 bit windows machine. instead x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc i use mingw32 gcc compiler the LSpng works properly.

Comment: @Siva: I mean: what was the command used to create `LSpng.lib`?

Comment: @MichaelBurr i don't use any command i created the LSpng.lib using the visual studio 2005 IDE.

Answer (score 0):

The object files you're compiling with MinGW-64 assume that they will be supported by (linked to) the MinGW runtime libraries. While linking C object files built with one compiler might work by happenstance when linked against another compiler's runtime (which seems to be happening for you with the 32-bit builds), that's not something that will work in the general case.

It will work much of the time for MinGW becuase it relies on the Windows system DLL MSVCRT.DLL for much of its runtime support - but not 100% of it.

For your 64-bit build you have:

- the `libpng` function `png_handle_sCAL()` (from `pngrutil.c`) wants to link to `__strtod`.  However, the symbol for that function in the VC library is an undecorated `strtod`. As a side note - looking at the source I couldn't see where `png_handle_sCAL()` made a call to `strtod()`. Perhaps you have a different version of the library that I downloaded.
- the `read_png` function (which I assume is in `pngreadwrite.c`) wants to link to `mingw_getsp` - a function that the MinGW library uses to help implement `setjmp` (and maybe other things). The 32-bit MinGW runtime doesn't use such a helper - it relies on the MSVCRT runtime for `setjmp` support. Obviously, there is no `mingw_getsp` function in the VC runtime.

For the `__strtod()` symbol there's this hint in a `stdlib.h` header in the 64-bit MinGW I have installed:

```
/* libmingwex.a provides a c99-compliant strtod() exported as __strtod() */
```

So you might be able to work around the `__strtod` unresolved external by including `libmingwex.a` in your set of libraries to link in.  It looks like it will also help with the `mingw_getsp` problem. But there's also a chance it might have its own set of externs that require some other library.

Comment: while i include libmingwex.a then i will get the following errors. "Error 1 error LNK2005: longjmp already defined in LSpng.lib(lib64_libmingwex_a-mingw_getsp.o) MSVCRTD.lib" "Error 2 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __mingw_raise_matherr referenced in function pow LSpng.lib
" "
Error 3 fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals E:\Siva\v1.0.0.4\Rel_4.1.0\LSpng\x64\Debug\Testpng.exe
"

Comment: @Siva: I'm not really surprised. Like I said, you're really treading into an unsupported area when trying to link one compiler's objects with another compiler's runtime.

Comment: @Siva: I don't know - build everything with one compiler or the other?  If you need to support both compilers, have a separate set of libraries for each toolchain with a clever naming convention to differentiate them. That seems to be what most (all?) libraries that support multiple toolchains do.